# When does my PS+ subscription end

Tags: ps4

I activated my 1 year PS+ Subscription around Christmas, will it end the next Christmas or the January 1st 2020 ?

Comment: Why would it end on January 1st 2020, ~7 days after you bought it?

Answer (score 1):

The PS+ membership will end next Christmas.

Answer (score 0):

“1 year” means exactly 365 days from the start of your membership, so your membership will end “around Christmas” next year.